# php handle curly array with foreach

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach

i am trying to handle curly {} array with php and foreach.
i have this array:

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
...
...
...
"son_options": {"2": "3", "7": "5", "10": "9", "6": "22"}
```

i am trying to do this:

```
foreach($_POST["variants"] as $data):
            $itemOptionsArr["itemid"]=$itemid;
            $itemOptionsArr["optionid"]=$data["optionid"];
            $itemOptionsArr["valueid"]=$data["optionvalueid"];
            $itemOptionsArr["price"]=$data["i_vprice"];
            $itemOptionsArr["pic"]=$data["i_photo"];
            $itemOptionsArr["quantity"]=$data["i_quantity"];
            if($data["son_options"]){
                foreach($data["son_options"] as $data2):
                    $itemOptionsArr["optionid"]= [0]2 or [1]7.....
                    $itemOptionsArr["valueid"]= [0]3 or [1]5....
                    $itemoptionsid=setItemOptions($itemOptionsArr);
                endforeach;
            }
            $itemoptionsid=setItemOptions($itemOptionsArr);
        endforeach;
```

i am trying to get the key and the value as parameters
for example:
"2":"3"

$par1 = 2;
$par2=3;

any help please?

Comment: and `$data` is ...?

Comment: That's passing the buck: `$_POST["variants"]` is ...? (remember the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask): show what is in the things your code is using, so that folks can meaningfully comment on the code). Also not that what you're trying to do should be a description, not code. Describe what you're trying to do, then show the ([mcve]) code that does that.

Comment: PHP does not natively handle json for you. You need to [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)...

Comment: in the beginning of the file i have: $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);

Comment: i updated the question and described what i am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

ok i found the solution...it's easy...

```
foreach($data["son_options"] as $key=>$val):
                    $itemOptionsArr["optionid"]= $key;
                    $itemOptionsArr["valueid"]= $val;
                    $itemoptionsid=setItemOptions($itemOptionsArr);
                endforeach;
```

thank you all.